# distribution of cosine of uniformly random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

let us consider following data

[image]

and here is its chart

[image]

generally cosine is not linear function,therefore  cosine of uniform variables should not be uniform as well,because if

$x=cos(y)$

$y=\arccos{x}$

according to this site

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56040/cosine-of-a-uniform-random-variable

as i understood cosine of uniform variables distributed in $|0, 2*\pi|$ is not again uniform variables right?  then what kind of  distribution it is supposed to be? thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The uniform distribution on $[-\pi, \pi]$ has constant probability density function $f_Y(y) = 2/\pi$ for all $y$. However if $x$ has uniform distribution on $[-\pi, \pi]$ and $y = \cos (x)$, then $y$ has probability density $f_Y(y) = (1/\pi)(1/\sqrt{1-y^2})$ which integrates to $1$ so it is a probability density, but it is unbounded because values close to $1$ become more and more likely. And so no, $\cos x$ is not uniformly distributed if $x$ is.

Comment: can we approximate is by some known distribution?

Comment: but  it never goes out of bounds right?what i mean will it go for instance out of $1$ or down to $-1$?

Comment: The distribution is only defined for $y$ in the open interval $(-1,1)$ so you'll never sample a value outside of that. (And the fact that endpoints are not defined in the density is not a problem, because the probability of getting any single point like $x = \pm \pi$ is always $0$ for a continuous distribution over an interval like uniform distribution over $[-\pi,\pi]$.)

Comment: The given density function is closed form and exact so I'm not sure what you mean by "approximate". It is definitely way different than other "well-known" distributions like Gaussian. If you want to approximate so you can sample, there is no need -- all you need to do is calculate the inverse cumulative distribution function $F^{-1}$ for the density and then sample $z$ uniformly from $[0,1]$ and then your sample is $F^{-1}(z)$.

Comment: how can i get this  form by myself?i mean which formula should i use?just for curiosity